# How to store pyramid structure in a database

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I would like to store pyramid structure in database preferably in NoSQL like `mongodb`.

So if I have a structure like below

```
    0
  0   0    <-tier 2
0   0   0  <-tier 1
```

*each zero is a node and each level is a tier and each node is connected to single next tier node

What I initially thought of doing is to store the `objectID` of the direct parent's node into each child's node - that way I can consecutively climb up the ladder by searching for nodes that are referenced by the previous node. However, that would require multiple queries to get to the top and I don't think it would be very favourable in terms of performance especially if I have to search for highest parent for many nodes.

So another way that I thought of was to store every single parent in order as an array into each node so that I can get the nth parent just by retrieving single node. However, it feels like this would lead to storing a lot of unnecessary data as opposed to the solution before.

Is there another way to solve this problem other than what I have come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pyramid structure is regular, you can store every element in an array without wasting space, and still work out where an element should go in the array from its position and vice versa.

If the number of elements in each row is 1,2,3,4,5... as you have drawn then the number of elements in the first n rows (counting from 1) is 1+2+3+..n = n(n+1)/2 (this is just the sum of an arithmetic progression). Counting from 1 again, element i in row j is at array offset counting from zero of j(j+1)/2 + i - 2. To find a row number from an array offset, you can just use binary chop.

Comment: oh I see but what if the pyramid structure is probably not going to be regular? Say for example it may really expand to the left side of the pyramid but not so much on the right side of the pyramid? if I use an array I would have to fill the empty spaces too. Also, the calculation efficiency seems to be same as each node storing the object id of its parent and cascading up?

Comment: If you have a regular structure you know which offsets you need to retrieve without having to follow pointers. If following pointers is more expensive than calculating offsets (for instance, if following pointers in the db means accessing external store) then this is an advantage. If the structure is not regular there are some strategies for using fairly standard SQL - https://medium.com/notes-from-a-messy-desk/representing-trees-in-postgresql-cbcdae419022 but the problem is hard enough that some databases treat it as a special case - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ltree.html